# Java Removing Redundant Items in Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, redundancy

For this particular problem I am attempting to remove redundant elements in an sorted array and replace them all with 0s at the **end** of the array. For example, if I had an array consisting of the int elements

1,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,7

My output array should be

1,3,4,5,6,7,0,0,0

My first attempt at the problem was to create a swapper in order to push all the 0s to the end of the list after removing the elements, but it won't seem to push the zeros to the end of the list. Here is my code.

```
 public void implode(int[] ary) 
    {
        int swapper = -1;

        int[] newARY = new int[ary.length];
        int current = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++)
        {
            if (current != ary[i])
            {
            newARY[i] = ary[i];
            current = ary[i];
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++)
        {
            if (ary[i] == 0)
            {
                if (ary[i + 1] != 0)
                {
                    swapper = ary[i + 1];
                    ary[i] = swapper;
                    ary[i + 1] = 0;
                }

            }

        }

        ary = newARY;
        for (int i = 0; i < newARY.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(newARY[i] + " ");
        }

    }
```

The array im testing it with is,

```
 int[] aryIn2 = {1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6};
```

However, when outputting the imploded array, I receive this one.

1 0 2 3 4 0 5 6

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need those zeros? As it defeats task of removing redundant elements in array(having multiple zeros, post running your `implode()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issue with you code that I observed.

1) Your swapper logic is performing swapping on a different array than the one in which you had done modification earlier

2) You need to have this logic in a bubble-sort way, i.e. loop inside a loop

Below is a working modified sample code of your method. I have modified only the second for-loop logic

```
public void implode(int[] ary) {
    int swapper = -1;

    int[] newARY = new int[ary.length];
    int current = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
        if (current != ary[i]) {
            newARY[i] = ary[i];
            current = ary[i];
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < newARY.length - 1; i++) {
        if (newARY[i] == 0 && newARY[i + 1] != 0) {
            for (int j = i; (j + 1) < newARY.length; j++) {
                swapper = newARY[j + 1];
                newARY[j] = swapper;
                newARY[j + 1] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < newARY.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(newARY[i] + " ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

not an answer to your problem, but using (if possible) java streams can shorten your way:

```
int[] arr = {1,3,3,4,4,5,6,6,7};

// distinct
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(arr).distinct().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

// pad with zero's
while(list.size() < arr.length) {
    list.add(0);
}

// display
System.out.println(list.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

will output

```
1,3,4,5,6,7,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

In this first loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
    if (current != ary[i]) {
        newARY[i] = ary[i];
        current = ary[i];
    }
}
```

You fill `newARY` with elements in `ary` with duplicated value turns to 0:

```
newARY: 1 0 2 3 4 0 5 6
```

However, in the second loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < ary.length; i++)
    {
        if (ary[i] == 0)
        {
            if (ary[i + 1] != 0)
            {
                swapper = ary[i + 1];
                ary[i] = swapper;
                ary[i + 1] = 0;
            }

        }

    }
```

You're modifying your original `ary` array. So the newARY is not updated.

However, your attempt to push 0 to the end of array also fail if there are more than two 0s consecutive. And it is also vulnerable to ArrayOutOfBoundIndexException since you try to read `ary[i+1]` without restriction on `i`

One simple and straight forward way to push 0s to the end of the array is to create new array with non-0s elements and fill 0s later:

```
int[] result = new int[ary.lenght];
int resultIndex = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < newARY.length; i++) {
    if (newARY[i] != 0) {
        result[resultIndex++] = newAry[i];
    }
}
for (int i = resultIndex; i < newARY.length; i++) {
    result[i] = 0;
}

// Print result array
```

Hint: Using above strategy, you can simplify your code. No need to create immediate array newARY. Just loop over the original array, push unique elements to the result array, then fill any slot left with 0s.